# adding alphabet letters for values with a do loop in sas

Tags: loops, sas, alphabet

```
data test;
length val $15;
input obs val $ pvalue;
cards;
1 demog 0.8812
2 ae 0.7112
3 dispostion 0.8234
4 exposure   0.7788
;
run;
```

I would like to get a new dataset with pvalue like 0.8812a, 0.7112b, 0.8234c, 0.7788d.
The real datasets in my hand are pretty long and following with the alphabet letters such as e, f, g, etc. Could you please help me solve this problem with a do loop in sas?

Thank you so much!

Comment: You need to be a lot clearer about what you are asking for.  A PVALUE cannot have a letter in it.  It is a number.  You want to make a new character variable? Why?  Why a,b,c instead of some other suffix.  What happens if there are more than 4 observations? More than 26?  What if one of the PVALUE actual values repeats? Should it get the same suffix the second time?

Comment: Well trained SAS developers avoid do-loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do something like this

```
data CLASS (drop = _h);
    set sasHelp.CLASS(rename =Height = _h);
    Heigth = cats(put(_h, 4.2), byte(rank('a') + _N_ - 1));
run;
```

but what exactly depends on your answers to Tom.